# Deriving show when using ExistentialQuantification extension?

Tags: haskell, existential-type

Why can't I derive Show here?

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}
data Obj = forall a. (Show a) => Item_Obj {get :: a, rest :: Obj} | No_Obj deriving Show

xs :: Obj
xs = Item_Obj 1 $ Item_Obj "foo" $ Item_Obj 'c' $ No_Obj

main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn . show $ xs
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Such kind of context in not allowed in haskell-98 datatypes. Read [this](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/GHC/Stand-alone_deriving_declarations)

Ofcourse you can write standalone instance by using `StandaloneDeriving` extension and let ghc do rest of the hardwork.

```
deriving instance Show Obj
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically because GHC's head explodes when you try that.  In other words, it simply hasn't been taught how to derive instances for existential types.  Wait for a few version numbers to pass and then try again.